# JavaEE web.xml - intepreting role-name tags

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss7.x, jaas

I want ask (or maybe better word is confirm) how after put more than one role name into auth-constraint tag given roles are treated. If to access to the app you nedd only one role from given set (after test it work that way) or user must have all specyfied roles? 
On example below I wonder if role "A **or** B" is needed or "A **and** B"?

I can't find official note about it. Does anyone know where I can confirm that operator beetwen role-name tag is OR? I don't want base on my test and result only.

My example is:

```
<security-constraint>
...
<auth-constraint>
    <description>Desc</description>
    <role-name>A</role-name>
    <role-name>B</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: You can accepts and promote my answer if it answers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is “OR”. In other words, you list in the element `auth-constraint` the list of roles that protect your `web-resource-collection`.  If after an authentication a principal have one of this roles he / she will be able to access to the resource collection.
In your case it is role A OR role B